# Convert Boolean JValue to parsable boolean string

Tags: xml, json.net

I have a web service that is parsing JSON requests and using values to set properties on an XML document.

For example, the following request

```
{ name: "Foo", isEnabled: true, size: 100 }
```

should update an XML document to this,

```
<SomeElement name="Foo" isEnabled="true" size="100" />
```

but instead it produces this:

```
<SomeElement name="Foo" isEnabled="True" size="100" />
```

I don't have structured types for either the JSON input or the XML I'm modifying (I'm the middle man here), so I parse the JSON into a `JObject` and the XML is a raw `XmlDocument`.

The problem is, that as I'm looking through the `JObject`, I get each properties JValue and convert it into a string to put into the XML attributes by calling `JValue.ToString()`.  For the integer and string values, this works fine, but for the boolean, `JValue.ToString()` results in `True/False`, instead of `true/false` so when the user of the XML document attempts to parse the XML document into their object, it fails because `True` is an invalid boolean value.

On the other hand, if I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` to convert the value, then the boolean and integer will work, but the string values will be quoted (as required by JSON).

Is there a better way to get the proper stringed value that I need, or do I just need to special case boolean `JValue`s in my conversion code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you need is in [`XmlNodeConverter.ConvertTokenToXmlValue()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs), which calls the correct [`XmlConvert.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload depending on JSON token type.  Unfortunately, it's not public.  The easiest way to access this method (other than to copy it's logic I suppose) is to create a temp `JObject` containing your `JValue`, convert it to an `XElement` with [`XmlNodeConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.htm), then return the value of the created `XElement`:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string ToXmlValue(this JValue value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        var obj = new JObject(new JProperty("a", value.DeepClone())); // XmlNodeConverter only works deserializing an object, so make a synthetic object.
        return obj.ToXElement().Value;
    }

    public static XElement ToXElement(this JObject obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        using (var reader = obj.CreateReader())
            return JsonExtensions.DeserializeXElement(reader);
    }

    public static XElement DeserializeXElement(JsonReader reader)
    {
        return DeserializeXElement(reader, null, false);
    }

    public static XElement DeserializeXElement(JsonReader reader, string deserializeRootElementName, bool writeArrayAttribute)
    {
        var converter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter() { DeserializeRootElementName = deserializeRootElementName, WriteArrayAttribute = writeArrayAttribute };
        var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { converter } });
        return jsonSerializer.Deserialize<XElement>(reader);
    }
}
```

This should handle all value type conversions to XML correctly - `DateTime`, `bool`, `decimal` and so on - with the correct internationalization.

You might also want to look at [Converting between JSON and XML](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.htm) to see if Json.NET's built-in conversion API can help you.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I can't just use the built in Json.NET conversion due to some issues they use around the loss of order info.  I'm picking this as the correct answer since it'll return the 'proper' serialized value for the available types.  Hopefully it doesn't end up being too costly.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method for `JValue` that gives the result you want:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string ToXmlFriendlyString(this JValue jv)
    {
        return (jv.Type == JTokenType.Boolean ? jv.ToString().ToLower() : jv.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then, wherever you are calling `JValue.ToString()` call the extension method instead, e.g.:

```
JValue jv = new JValue(true);
Console.WriteLine(jv.ToXmlFriendlyString());
```

Comment: Probably the most efficient option but I was hoping to avoid having to special case various types.